# Digits of $\pi$ using Integer Arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods, pi, computational-mathematics, integers

How can I compute the first few decimal digits of $\pi$ using only integer arithmetic? By 'integer arithmetic' I mean the operations of addition, subtraction, and multiplication with both operands as integers, integer division, and exponentiation with a positive integer exponent. The first hundred decimal digits or so would be sufficient if the method is not a completely general one.

By 'compute', I mean that I would like to obtain subsequent digits of $\pi$ one-by-one, printing them to the screen as I go along.

(Context: I'm writing a Befunge-98 program...)

Comment: Wait, if you can raise integers to integer powers, can you represent $2^{-1}$, for example?

Comment: Since you're looking for a decimal representation of $\pi$, you're dealing with rational numbers. I'm pretty sure you can't escape the realm of integers if you can't construct rational numbers if you don't use some sort of division. However, when you say you're looking for *digits* of $\pi$, do you literally want the digits or do you seek an actual rational approximation of $\pi$?

Comment: I want the digits, so that I can print them as I go along computing them. And I have integer division.

Comment: And you want the decimal digits? (The situation turns out to be different in binary or hexadecimal vs. decimal.)

Comment: Indeed, finding the hexademical representation of $\pi$ is straightforward with the BBP formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (or rather a) spigot algorithm for $\pi$ does exactly that: extract digits of $\pi$ one by one based entirely on integer arithmetic. See [this](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf) paper.

Comment: Hey, buddy! 2/3 of your links are now dead. Could you please update them? ^^

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to start with the beginning of the continued fraction for $\pi$ as input data

```
3, 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 84, 2, 1, 1, 15, 3, 13, 1, 4, 2, 6, 6, 99, 1, 2, 2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 1, 6, 8, 1, 7, 1, 2, 3, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 16, 1, 161, 45, 1, 22, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 24, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1
```

(see http://oeis.org/A001203) you can compute the approximations $P_n/Q_n$ with integer arithmetic. You can use the value of $Q_n$ to estimate the number of correct decimal digits you will get when you compute its decimal expansion (Theorem 5 on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).

That page has formulas for $P_n$ and $Q_n$ - it calls them $h_n$ and $k_n$.

This algorithm is *probably* not a good one for producing the digits one at a time without deciding in advance how many you want. In that respect it's like the sieve of Eratosthenes for listing primes.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Also, how do I know how many correct digits I have with each approximation? If I know that, then I can multiply by the correct power of ten and do integer division, but like you said, it's not really producing digits one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is this paper by Simon Plouffe

http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0303

And it is about *decimal* digits.