# Spigot algorithms for transcendental numbers

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, transcendental-numbers

I'm trying to write a program that will compute digits of transcendental numbers using a spigot algorithm. While researching, I found the [BBP Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula), and a [Compendium of BBP-Type Formulas](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/dhbpapers/bbp-formulas.pdf), alas, I can't seem to find formulas for numerous other constants (eg. $e$, $\gamma$, etc.).

I'm particularly interested in finding BBP-Type formulas because this would allow me to implement a single algorithm that could deal with many constants uniformly.

If that's not the case, is there a reference of spigot algorithms for transcendental constants around? (I haven't found any myself).

Comment: You may want to check out spigot algorithms for continued fractions. There are algorithms that use spigot algorithms for $x$ and $y$ to produce the continued fraction for $x+y$, for instance.

Comment: The reference I was looking for was HAKMEM; start reading around page 36: ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-239.pdf

Comment: I think [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585749/digits-of-pi-using-integer-arithmetic) is relevant, but it's specifically about $\pi$.